# Search by student entity ID using PHP native

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have question regarding a search box: I have a search `txtbox` that will search the class `schedule`.

What I'm doing is I search the `student id`, it runs successfully like when I search id number `2004-02039` or `2003-2938`.

When I search number like `44` it successfully says "no results found". Which means it is correct. But my problem is when I search `1` it will display the whole, when I search `2` it displays the whole data again. I want that when I search `1` it will go to "No results found".

Can someone help me? My type of `student_id` is `varchar` and I use the script `LIKE` to search the same names in the database. (Sorry I'm using the old `mysql_query`).

Here's my code:

```
<div class="news_box">
      <center><h2>My Class Schedule </h2>   </center>   
      <div id="tfheader">
        <form id="tfnewsearch" action="schedule.php?" method="get">
          <input type="text"  name="search" placeholder="ID Number" size="21" maxlength="120" />
          <input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton" />
        </form>

        <div class="tfclear"></div>
      </div>

        <a href="#"></a>

        <p><center>
        <?php require("scripts/DataConnect.php"); ?>
        <?php include("search.php");?>

        <table width="728" height="121" border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#888" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; ">
        <tr>
          <th>Offer Code </th>
          <th>Subject</th>
          <th>Day</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Units</th>
          <th>Room</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
          if($_GET['search'] != ''){
            if($row_count != 0){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
                 echo  "<tr>
                        <td>".$row['offer_code']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['subject']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['time']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['day']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['units']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['room_number']."</td>
                       </tr>";
                }
              }else{
                echo "<tr>
                        <td colspan='6' style='text-align:center;'>No RESULTS FOUND.</td>
                      </tr>";
              }
          }else{
            echo "<tr>
                    <td colspan='6' style='text-align:center;'>PLEASE SEARCH CLASS SCHEDULE.</td>
                  </tr>";
          }
        ?>
        </table>
        </center></p>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
        </div>
```

And my `search.php` file:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
  $query = "SELECT 
              student_record.student_id,
              class_schedule.student_id,
              class_schedule.offer_code,
              class_schedule.subject,
              class_schedule.time,
              class_schedule.day,
              class_schedule.units,
              class_schedule.room_number
              FROM
              student_record
              INNER JOIN class_schedule ON class_schedule.student_id = student_record.student_id
              WHERE 
              student_record.student_id LIKE '%".$search."%'
                        ";
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  $row_count = mysql_num_rows($res);
?>
```

Comment: You're doing a wilcard search, e.g. `%1%` is going to find **ALL** records that contain the `1` character. If you want exact matches only, then you'd have to have `student_id='$search'` instead.

Comment: ok i see, how will i able to block that? like if i search 1 it will said no results found

Comment: You should dump the SQL statement before executing, for easier debugging.  Add an 'echo $query;' right before the $res = mysql_query... line.  Most likely you will find the culprit here. Much easier to find things that aren't translating properly by simply analyzing the actual query that gets executed.

Comment: no its not working what im talking about is when i search 1 all the matches will display

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using LIKE, try this:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
  $query = "SELECT 
              student_record.student_id,
              class_schedule.student_id,
              class_schedule.offer_code,
              class_schedule.subject,
              class_schedule.time,
              class_schedule.day,
              class_schedule.units,
              class_schedule.room_number
              FROM
              student_record
              INNER JOIN class_schedule ON class_schedule.student_id = student_record.student_id
              WHERE 
              student_record.student_id ='".$search."'
                        ";
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  $row_count = mysql_num_rows($res);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. Nice and easy!

Comment: I think he wants to return all partial matches, thus he was correct in using the LIKE statement.  He's saying if he searches for '1', the query returns all matches, even those without a '1' in them.  Am I correct?

Comment: yes @Ryan Griggs that's what im talking about, it will return all the matched when i search 1

Comment: Again, please have your script dump the final SQL query before executing, and please post here so we can see where the problem arises.

Comment: @RyanGriggs good idea, I think my suggestion would work in theory, might be a typo in there or something.

Comment: What Ryan is saying is to put echo $query; before the $res = mysql_query($query); line. We can then see what query is being run in MySQL, can you post the output of that please?

Comment: the problem is when i search 1 all the data in the database will display instead it will goes to no results found but when i search 2 it will display again, same . BUt when i search 44 it executes correctly and when i search the student id it display also correctly the problem is only when i search 1 or search 2 or search 3 numbers

Comment: ok here's the output

SELECT student_record.student_id, class_schedule.student_id, class_schedule.offer_code, class_schedule.subject, class_schedule.time, class_schedule.day, class_schedule.units, class_schedule.room_number FROM student_record INNER JOIN class_schedule ON class_schedule.student_id = student_record.student_id WHERE student_record.student_id LIKE '%2%'

Comment: The student_record.student_id LIKE '%2%' is still there. That's the bit you need to change to student_record.student_ID = '2';

Comment: Your SQL statement looks right, but you understand that a search for "2" would return all results with a "2" *anywhere* in the number, right?  Example: 2000-4567 and 1345-9002 would both be returned when searching for "2".  Am I correctly understanding what you are attempting to do?

Comment: yes that's very correct @Ryan Griggs its beacause of that any number thats why it will return the same data

Comment: can you help me on how to do that a better way?

Comment: If you only want exact matches, then @dwjv gave the exact right answer.  You could also allow the user to select "exact match" or "partial match" from the search, then use one or the other method in your query.  Or you could allow the person performing the search to enter the % characters manually if desired.  In this way the searcher could customize a search, for example '123%' finds all matches starting with 123, where '%123' finds all matches ending with 123.  This gives the user the most power, but requires a bit more knowledge of the system.

Answer (score -1):

You should try **mysqli** module (PHP Native) it's too easy, here an [example](http://efunctions.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/uso-de-mysqli-en-php/) on my blog.

I hope this helps!